# No Results in GET/V1/orders Request with filters

Tags: orders

I'm facing an issue while using the Magento Commerce API. I'm trying to make a **GET** request to the */V1/orders* endpoint with a filter on the `created_at` field to retrieve orders created after a specific date and time. However, even though I receive `totalPage = 3` in the response, the items field is empty.

Here's my request:

```
GET /V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2023-11-10 13:08:31&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=gt&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

Response

```
{
"items": [],
"search_criteria": {
"filter_groups": [
 {
  "filters": [
    {
      "field": "created_at",
      "value": "2023-11-10 13:08:31",
      "condition_type": "gt"
    }
  ]
 }
],
"sort_orders": [],
"page_size": 0,
"current_page": 0
},
"total_count": 3
}
```

If I adjust the created_at filter one hour forward like this

```
GET /V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2023-11-10 13:08:31&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=gt&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

I receive the following response:

```
{
"items": [],
"search_criteria": {
"filter_groups": [
 {
  "filters": [
    {
      "field": "created_at",
      "value": "2023-11-10 13:08:31",
      "condition_type": "gt"
    }
  ]
 }
],
"sort_orders": [],
"page_size": 0,
"current_page": 0
},
"total_count": 0
}
```

I have 3 orders created after 14:08 that don't seem to be retrieved in both cases, whereas they are retrieved correctly when fetching all orders.

I'm having difficulty comprehending why these three orders are not being retrieved. Is it possible that the date format in the Magento database differs (which I don't have direct access to), or could the issue be related to my filtering, or is there some other factor at play?

#### Edit

After Dava answer I run a new test with 2 orders at different day, and everything worked correctly (even with my initial date format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Hub looking at your request id suggest you make sure that the date format in your request is correct and compatible with Magento's expected format. Magento usually uses the ISO 8601 date format, so your date should be in the format 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'. In your case, the provided date '2023-11-10 13:08:31' should be formatted as '2023-11-10T13:08:31Z'.

Modify your request to:

```
GET /V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2023-11-10T13:08:31Z&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=gt&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

Comment: Thank you, your response worked :) I also found another thing that surprised me. The three orders I managed to retrieve now have a different date compared to the administrator panel's order view. When fetched through the API, it shows 13:09, while in the administrator panel, it's 14:09. I can't understand the reason for this time difference.

Comment: That is your server time. you posted the original comment at 15:07 which means you did the call about an hour earlier so you submitted the call about 14:09 meaning what when it hit your server it inserted 13:09 as your server time is an hour earlier than the actual time.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. I copy/pasted on postman and it works fine for me. I would suggest to look at the endpoint you are hitting. Maybe you are requesting to a wrong env.

Another possible issue could be store_code. Make sure you are sending store_code in the url. Like this

/rest/{{store}}/V1/orders

Comment: Thank you for your response :) In my case @davagordon answer works